# WHM Excessive processes running under user

Tags: process, whm

At least twice a aday I got an email from my WHM server very similar to the below for different processes.
When I check the process manager of WHM I don't see the processes with the same PID.
Also evertthing seems normal and I don't get any complaint from the users.

What does this message mean?
How can I fix it?
Thank you.

Time:          Fri Jul 15 11:34:29 2016 +0300
Account:       mysite
Process Count: 12 (Not killed)

Process Information:

User:mysite PID:28310 PPID:24760 Run Time:100(secs) Memory:187524(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/add.php
User:mysite PID:28320 PPID:28048 Run Time:100(secs) Memory:186880(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/add.php
User:mysite PID:28321 PPID:27447 Run Time:100(secs) Memory:186360(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/report.php
User:mysite PID:28332 PPID:28141 Run Time:100(secs) Memory:186880(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/add.php
User:mysite PID:28333 PPID:27450 Run Time:100(secs) Memory:186360(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/report.php
User:mysite PID:28344 PPID:25013 Run Time:99(secs) Memory:186880(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/add.php
User:mysite PID:28346 PPID:27867 Run Time:99(secs) Memory:186360(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/report.php
User:mysite PID:28380 PPID:28318 Run Time:94(secs) Memory:186620(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/post.php
User:mysite PID:28382 PPID:28348 Run Time:92(secs) Memory:186620(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/post.php
User:mysite PID:28734 PPID:28652 Run Time:56(secs) Memory:186620(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/post.php
User:mysite PID:28761 PPID:28653 Run Time:54(secs) Memory:186620(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/post.php
User:mysite PID:28793 PPID:27855 Run Time:51(secs) Memory:186620(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/post.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems wordpress is installed under that particular hosting account which is causing the problem and it is due to php memory limit. This is due to php variable data being stored in the memory that is not cleared while the php scripts are running. Let's get it fix by making some changes within your php.ini file.

- Login to WHM
- Go to Service Configuration and click on Configuration Editor
- Click on Advanced mode
- Find memory_limit and change the value if it is 128MB then change it to 256MB (if it is 256MB then change it to 512MB)
- Save the Changes
- Reboot Server

Done!

Comment: Hi, From here Home »Service Configuration »PHP Configuration Editor I see that the memory_limit is -1 ?

Comment: Change it to 128MB OR 256MB

Comment: would be great if you could made this one reviewed if your issue got resolved :)

Comment: Hi I still get similar messages  User:mysite PID:4645 PPID:4105 Run Time:66(secs) Memory:118620(kb) exe:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/522/bin/perl cmd:cpanellogd - http logs for 

User:mysite PID:5958 PPID:4902 Run Time:10(secs) Memory:187192(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/edit_task_process.php
User:mysite PID:5959 PPID:4995 Run Time:10(secs) Memory:187192(kb) exe:/usr/bin/php cmd:/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/add_org.php
User:mysite PID:5960 PPID:4998 Run Time:10(secs)